Error when running voskros on Windows
So following the below link I have downloaded and build the voskros tool under Ros2 in Windows 10 (Python 3.8):
https://github.com/bob-ros2/voskros
But when I run the execute command:
ros2 run voskros vosk

I get the following error :
C:\ros2\ros2-windows\speech_recognition_ros\src>ros2 run voskros vosk -l
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ros2\ros2-windows\Scripts\ros2-script.py", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('ros2cli==0.32.1', 'console_scripts', 'ros2')())
  File "C:\ros2\ros2-windows\Lib\site-packages\ros2cli\cli.py", line 91, in main
    rc = extension.main(parser=parser, args=args)
  File "C:\ros2\ros2-windows\Lib\site-packages\ros2run\command\run.py", line 70, in main
    return run_executable(path=path, argv=args.argv, prefix=prefix)
  File "C:\ros2\ros2-windows\Lib\site-packages\ros2run\api\__init__.py", line 64, in run_executable
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 not a valid Win32 application

In addition if I execute the following command:
ros2 launch voskros voskros.launch.yaml model:=fr

I get the following error:
[ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): executable 'vosk' not found on the libexec directory 'somepath/'

Any clues?
